# MPDF not displaying any error but not generating PDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

For now, I am trying to use the [MDF1](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) to generate PDF. I am trying to start up with the example first but I only get a blank page on the files which should generate the PDF and no PDF is generated as well.

I have added:

`error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

at the start of the file and

`$mpdf->debug = true;`

but I still don't see any error.

I have set **ttfontdata**, **tmp**, and **graph_cache** directories permission to 777 but I still can't get it to work.

Is there something I need to check in order to get this library to work on my setup?

I have tried this on my local setup and the same code works fine so I think it's definitely something on my server setup.

Edit: (here is the code I am starting with)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$html = '
<h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
<h2>Basic HTML Example</h2>
This file demonstrates most of the HTML elements.';


//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================

include("../mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 

$mpdf->debug = true;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();

exit;

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
```

Comment: just check whether your html is proper. unclosed html tags used to cause such thing to me in past.

Comment: @Gunnrryy I don't think it's anything from the HTML because I am just using the examples the I have downloaded with the library and didn't touch the files yet.

Comment: well, then it would be helpful, if you post some of your code too.

Comment: I've added the sample code. I'm not really sure if the code has any issue. It's probably some settings or permission I am missing. @Gunnrryy

Comment: make sure you have mbstring module installed.

Comment: It is already installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148639/discussion-between-gunnrryy-and-atasha).

Answer (score 0):

check in `index.php` if

`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');`

then change it to

`define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

now all the errors will be dispalyed